# Minimum binary tree problem running infinite loop

Tags: c++, debugging, binary-tree, infinite-loop, minimum-spanning-tree

This C++ code is not terminating in Vscode. Can you explain why?

**Here is the code**

> minimum of two numbers

```
int min(int x,int y)
{
    if(x<y) 

        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
```

> filling the minimum of siblings as parent in a binary tree

```
void minimumtree(int arr[], int b, int n)

{

    if(b==0)
        return;
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i+2)
        {
            int x=(b+i)/2;
            arr[x]=min(arr[b+i],arr[b+i+1]);
        }
        minimumtree(arr,b/2,n/2);
    }
}

int main()

{
```

> leaf input n- number of leaves, b - beginning of index of the first leaf in an array

```
    int n,b; cin>>n>>b; int arr[n+b];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[b+i];
```

> query input

```
int t;
cin>>t;
int q[t];

for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    cin>>q[i];

minimumtree(arr,b,n);
```

> query output

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    cout<<arr[q[i]];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i+2` doesn't update `i`. It's a no-op. `i` is still zero afterwards.

Comment: `int q[t];` -- `int arr[n+b];` -- These arrays are not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ have the number of entries denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector` instead.  Second, `VSCode` is not a C++ compiler -- it is a code editor -- if you installed Visual C++, the code you posted will not compile due to what was mentioned about those arrays.

Comment: Can i+=2 be used instead?

Comment: Let the tags describe themselves, don't put that in the title.

Comment: @xikram to answer your question, yes `i += 2;` would work in the for loop

Comment: Well, what happens when you try `i+=2`?

Comment: i+=2 is the same as i=i+2, it updates i by 2.

Answer (score 0):

be clearer may help

```
int min(int x,int y) {

    return x<y ? x: y;

}

     // filling the minimum of siblings as parent in a binary tree

void minimumtree(int arr[], int b, int n) {

    if(b) {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i+=2)
        {
            int x=(b+i)/2;
            arr[x]=min(arr[b+i],arr[b+i+1]);
        }
        minimumtree(arr,b/2,n/2);
    }

    return;

}

int main() {

   // leaf input n- number of leaves, b - beginning of index of the first leaf in an array

 int n,b;
 cin>>n>>b;
 int *arr = new int[n+b];  // size is in run-time so define or set it dynamically

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        cin>>arr[b+i];
   // query input

int t;
cin>>t;
int q = new int[t];

for(int i=0; i<t; ++i)
    cin>>q[i];

minimumtree(arr,b,n);

   // query output

for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    cout<<arr[q[i]];
return 0;
}
```